# how can i add wild card to query text in solr search

Tags: search, solr, lucene

I want that if someone search for   `phan` then `elephant` Should match.

Now i have `value:*phan*` then it works so i tried this

```
<analyzer type="query">
    <filter class="solr.PatternReplaceFilterFactory" pattern="(.+)" replacement="*$1*" replace="all" />
```

But then its making the query as 
`"*phan*"` as single field not wilcard

how can i do that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make Solr find documents for word parts, you need to have a look at [the NGramTokenizer](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Tokenizers#Tokenizers-N-GramTokenizer) or [the Edge NGramTokenizer](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Tokenizers#Tokenizers-EdgeN-GramTokenizer). As you are required to match parts of the word within the middle of it, you should have a look at the NGramTokenizer. If the start and end of the word would do, the EdgeNGram would be favourable, as it is smaller in index terms.

A good sample is found here on SO within the question [Apache solr search part of the word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1974394/apache-solr-search-part-of-the-word).

**Why Indexing over query time?**

Lucene and as such Solr are not meant to do searches with leading wildcards. So even search for `*foo` is likely to cause bad performance. Not to mention `*foo*`. You can read this up in [the FAQs 'What wildcard search support is available from Lucene?'](http://wiki.apache.org/lucene-java/LuceneFAQ#What_wildcard_search_support_is_available_from_Lucene.3F)

> Leading wildcards (e.g. *ook) are **not** supported by the QueryParser by default. As of Lucene 2.1, they can be enabled by calling QueryParser.setAllowLeadingWildcard( true ). Note that this can be an expensive operation: it requires scanning the list of tokens in the index in its entirety to look for those that match the pattern.

In the SO question [Understanding Lucene leading wildcard performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11766351/understanding-lucene-leading-wildcard-performance) is a more detailed write up on this topic.

Comment: I want to apply it on query not index analyser. can i do that

Comment: I dont understand what is that simple thing not included in solr. With N gram and edge gram , suppose i have 20 character long word , so it mean , system has to index all 15 more words to do partial match. is that efficeint

Comment: It is more efficient to _index_ the solution for a search if you can. You invest the computational time required one time only, at index time. If you want to do that _every_ time on query time, you will face higher CPU usage and poorer search performance.